# Query on Arimax results

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, usage-statistics, arima

We’ve run Arimax models in R. We had a lot of queries around the interpretation of the outputs and how businesses use these results.

Dataset has quarterly growth variables from 2014 - 2018 (Train data)
Test data contains data quarterly data for 2019.

Dependent variable = Volume (Growth %)
Independent Variables = 10 Macroeconomic variables (Growth %)

When we ran the model, we got 3 variables in the model.

Following is the line of code

```
Arimax.Model <- auto.arima(y = input.data[,"Volume"], 
                           xreg = input.data[,model.vars], 
                           seasonal = F)
```

Following is the output

```
Series: input.data[, "Volume"] 
Regression with ARIMA(0,0,0) errors 

Coefficients:
      Birth_Rate_Change  Proportion_Female_labour  Females_20_39
                97.7658                     1.370        19.7528
s.e.            23.8575                     0.305         3.9874

sigma^2 estimated as 4.316:  log likelihood=-24.07
AIC=56.15   AICc=61.86   BIC=58.09
```

Query – 
1.  Could you help us understand the interpretation of the coefficients obtained? Even if it’s not a growth model, how would we interpret the coefficients? Can we quantify the impact of the variables on Volume?

2. Is there a limit on the number of regressors we can get in the model in ARIMAX modeling exercise in R? This is because we are only getting 3 regressors at max.

Will be very thankful if you could provide answers to our queries.

Comment: this post is more suitable for cross validated. post it here for faster answer: [cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)